# Not able to resolve the directory paths with child_process exec call in Node.js

Tags: node.js

What i am trying to do:

I am tying to create an search engine with Node.js

What i have done so far:

I created a test program in Java and done the POC whether the search is being performed correctly or not. And its working perfectly with the command prompt. Then i exported the program into executable JAR file and executed that JAR file via the command prompt successfully.

Now i am trying to give web interface to this program via Node.js and trying to call the JAR file from it. So far i have managed all the bits and pieces on views and routers for application. But now when i am trying to call the JAR file using the Node child process facing error as -

stderr: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exec error: Error: Command failed: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My code which is giving error is as below -

```
     var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;


     child = exec('C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin java -jar C:\\java\\ease.jar '+ newstr,

     function (error, stdout, stderr){

     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);

     console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

     if(error !== null){

             console.log('exec error: ' + error);

      }

      });
```

I tried to search the API and google too but no avail, as i am not able to figure out how to give correctly the path string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), the first argument is `The command to run, with space-separated arguments`. So, it thinks the executable to execute is `C:\Program` since there is a space after `Program`. Also, it seems you might be missing a `\` after `bin` and before `java` or that you don't need to provide the path.

The following might work (unsure and unable to test):

```
exec('"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java" -jar C:\\java\\ease.jar '+ newstr);
```